# Using Lookup or Index - If a certain placing, then place the name

Tags: if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, match, lookup

I would like to provide the name of the competitor if they placed first. In different cells, I will like the same for second place to fifth place.

My purpose is because there are many divisions, 27, and each are on different worksheets. It would make it easier to have all the top five division placings on one sheet for the announcer and passing out trophies.

I am unable to provide a picture until I have a rep of 10. Therefore, the data is provided below.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Column B
Competitor Name

1. Brown, Sam
2. Simmons, Donald
3. Smith, John
4. Doe, John
5. Lee, Joe
6. Smith, Joey
7. Smith, Joey
8. Smith, Joey

Column C
Placings

1. 5
2. 4
3. 2
4. 6
5. 8
6. 7
7. 1
8. 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the formula, but before hand I had to make sure the data was in ascending order:

```
=LOOKUP(1,C1:C8,B1:B8)
```

Formula returned - Smith, Joey

```
=LOOKUP(2,C1:C8,B1:B8)
```

Formula returned - Smith, John

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another formula so the numbers do not need to be in any particular order:

```
=INDEX(B1:B8,MATCH(1,C1:C8,0),1)
```

Formula returned - Smith, Joey

```
=INDEX(B1:B8,MATCH(2,C1:C8,0),1)
```

Formula returned - Smith, John